# How to add a unit to the Xaxis tooltip with highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have this chart :

[image]

I want to add a unit to the value "4" (value of my xAxis). How can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
 tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2,
        valuePrefix: '$',
        valueSuffix: ' USD'
    }
```

please check the below link

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/valuedecimals/

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell because no code sent but it looks like your "4" is a series name (or some text item - not a value). To do this you can use the [`tooltip.formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) like in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/G3R2Y/). I have added the "%" to the category (month) text:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        return 'The value for <b>'+ this.x +
            '%</b> is <b>'+ this.y +'</b>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that from tooltip formatter

```
tooltip: {
formatter:function(){
var formattedX = "unit" + this.x;
return formattedX + 'this value ' + this.y;
}
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [tooltip.headerFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.headerFormat), see: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/647/

```
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 10px">{point.key} cm</span><br/>'
    },
```